# looking for a better way to organize 'where' statements in sql

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm quite new to SQL and I'm working on a problem to learn about it, but I'm a bit stuck.

Here's the task: *In a CRM System there are two tables, “Contacts” (ContactID, Name, CreateDate) and “ContactActivities” (ContactID, Activity, ActivityDate). Whenever something is modified in the CRM for a contact, a new activity is added to the ContactActivities table with the ContactID of the contact and a string Activity describing the activity.
Create a query which indicates for each contact whether a certain activity has happened (1) or not (0). The activity should have happened within a certain time period from the creation of the contact (take 2 weeks).*

[image: example tables]

Here's what I came up with (which seems to work, by checking with SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f3e42/85)):

```
  (SELECT SIGN(COUNT(*))
    FROM ContactActivities AS c2 
    WHERE c2.Activity = 'opt-in'
      AND c2.ContactID = c1.ContactID
      AND (SELECT MIN(c2.ActivityDate) - c1.CreationDate) < 14
  ) AS OPT_IN,
  (SELECT SIGN(COUNT(*))
    FROM ContactActivities AS c2 
    WHERE c2.Activity = 'purchase'
      AND c2.ContactID = c1.ContactID
      AND (SELECT MIN(c2.ActivityDate) - c1.CreationDate) < 14
  ) AS PURCHASE,
  (SELECT SIGN(COUNT(*))
    FROM ContactActivities AS c2 
    WHERE c2.Activity = 'deleted'
      AND c2.ContactID = c1.ContactID
      AND (SELECT MIN(c2.ActivityDate) - c1.CreationDate) < 14
  ) AS DELETED
FROM Contacts as c1
```

Now I'm wondering (and I'm quite sure actually) that this can be done with some better nesting of the `WHERE` statements - but I don't really know how.

I'm happy about any help!

Comment: Read about GROUP BY.

Comment: Images of your tables aren't useful, because they can't be copied and pasted in order to create test data to use when reesarching an answer. Instead, provide the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements needed to create those sample tables. You should also provide a tag for the specific DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using a join and aggregation:

```
SELECT c1.ContactID
     , MAX(CASE WHEN c2.Activity = 'opt-in'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPT_IN
     , MAX(CASE WHEN c2.Activity = 'purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PURCHASE
     , MAX(CASE WHEN c2.Activity = 'deleted'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DELETED
  FROM      Contacts          AS c1
  LEFT JOIN ContactActivities AS c2
    ON c2.ContactID = c1.ContactID
   AND c2.ActivityDate - c1.CreationDate < 14
 GROUP BY c1.ContactID
;
```

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f3e42/103)

Answer (score 1):

would check for a positive `sum` for condition `case when then else end`, by contactid:

```
select c.CONTACTID
  , sum(case when ACTIVITY='opt-in'   and datediff(ACTIVITYDATE, CREATIONDATE)<=14 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 as OPT_IN
  , sum(case when ACTIVITY='purchase' and datediff(ACTIVITYDATE, CREATIONDATE)<=14 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 as PURCHASE
  , sum(case when ACTIVITY='deleted'  and datediff(ACTIVITYDATE, CREATIONDATE)<=14 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 as DELETED
from contacts c
left join contactActivities a
on a.CONTACTID = c.CONTACTID
group by c.CONTACTID
;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bac0df/12)